# AngularJS passing parameters to controller without question mark

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way to pass data to controller without including a question mark ?

For example :

When i do this :

```
$location.path("/inventory/product").search({                       
  id: 1
});
```

The end url looks like `localhost:16684/#/inventory/product?id=8`.
How can i make it so that it looks like `localhost:16684/#/inventory/product/8` ?

Here is my route config :

```
{
  url: '/inventory/product',
  controller: 'inventory',
  config: {
    title: 'Products',
    templateUrl: 'app/views/inventory.html'
  }
},
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to share data between controllers you can use $rootScope instead of $scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write it like this :

```
$location.path("/inventory/product/"+id)
```

add a second route, and make it go to the same controller

```
{
  url: '/inventory/product',
  controller: 'inventory',
  config: {
    title: 'Products',
    templateUrl: 'app/views/inventory.html'
  }
},
{
  url: '/inventory/product/:id',
  controller: 'inventory',
  config: {
    title: 'Products',
    templateUrl: 'app/views/inventory.html'
  }
},
```